# ¿Cómo mostrar un tipo de dato Double completo en Java, es que lo pinta con un exponente 3.54966e-12?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Tengo un servicio en Java que se conecta a una base datos y obtiene datos de una tabla, posterior esos datos son mostrados en Angular, pero por ejemplo algunos tipos de datos que en la BD estan como **number**, yo los mapie como tipo **Double** en Java y lo muestra asi

> 3.54966e-12

cuando quiero que se muestre completo como en la base de datos

> 0.00000000000354966

como puedo hacer que se muestren de esa forma en Java?
o directamente en Angular como se podria hacer mas sencillo?

Answer (score 0):

Java lo puedes hacer con ***printf*** te quedaria:

```
System.out.printf("%nEl valor es %.18f\n", valor);
```

donde %.18f es la cantidad de decimales que quieres mostrar, si necesitas más solo le aumentas a 20, 21, etc.
valor = la variable Double que contiene la cantidad